# what is the minimum access level on a sql server the asp.net membership need?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, permissions, asp.net-membership, database-permissions

for security reason, what is the minimum access level the asp.net membership user could have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my investigations over here: [ASP.Net Membership.DeleteUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473060/asp-net-membership-deleteuser), the user would need SELECT and EXECUTE permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Better to use the application roles provided in the database.

These are documented on MSDN in page ["Roles and Views in the Application Services Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms164596) for SQL Server". This includes which operations require which role.

NB. You can also use SQL Management Studio to look at what is secured for each of the roles.